# MongoDB in master slave mode and guarantee writing

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, replication, master-slave

I got some problems with using mongoDB.

I use mongoDB in Master-Slave mode in 2 shards. Each shard has 3 members of Replica Set: 1 master and 2 slaves. When I'm writing document in mode REPLICA_SAFE or REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED and if I try to read it right away (after 3-5 ms), I don't have a guarantee that document will be finded in Replicas. Using Write Concern - REPLICA_SAFE or REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED. Using readPreference - secondaryPreferred.

Please, tell me, what I'm doing wrong? What should I do to reach guarantee writing with confirmation from all members of Replica Sets? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you looking to read from secondaries? Is it intended to be for scaling? Generally... "Replica sets provide redundancy and high availability" (from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/). Sharding is generally the way to scale "Sharding solves the problem with horizontal scaling" (from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)

Answer (score 0):

A majority replica write will only write to a majority of the members.

For example, if you read from a secondary that that did not acknowledge the write then you won't get it back; a.k.a. you CANNOT guarantee strong consistentcy here.

The only way you might be able to enforce strong consistentcy is to send the write to ALL members of the replica set. This of course poses multiple problems, for example what happens if one member does not acknowledge back (failover, latency, etc)? There is no way to ensure that all members of a replica set actually get the write frankly.

Comment: "without compromising availability" should be added to the last sentence IMHO